# Allowing access to completed course

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

I have a course with quiz. I send completion status ('completed'), success status ('passed') and score to LMS upon quiz completion. In LMS I can see that course is blocked and I can only 'finish completion' after completing quiz. I use local LMS (WebTutor 3.3).

I want to allow user to come later to improve his results. Is it something I can do within SCO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extend the answer a bit, normally `cmi.suspend_data` allows the content to store answers in a string format. This can be delimited simply, or be a native JavaScript Object/Array that gets stringified by JSON.  You have options more or less for how you could save structured data if you need it.

In order to resume @Rycochet is correct you would need to suspend.  But this also means you need to give them some option for setting "Done" or "Finish" or they may become perpetually in progress.

### What's the difference between a `cmi.exit` type of 'suspend' vs 'normal'

If the Content is left in 'suspend' it would appear like it was in-progress.  I've seen other LMS systems extend a "Done" button outside of the SCO but this is normally a custom addition.
When the student exits normally, the LMS would create a new attempt (clean) if the LMS allows for re-tries.  Or the LMS may only launch the content in review mode.  Review (`cmi.mode`) typically does not allow for further changes to the student attempt to occur.
At the same time the `cmi.entry` state will change to 'resume' vs. 'ab-initio' - latin for 'the beginning'.  Some LMS's just respond '' which is why I always check to see if their is suspend_data to tell if I've been here before more reliably.

This all greatly depends if the SCO supports review, and suspend.  If not you have to build that out so it can put the pages back the way the student left them.  Populating answers fields, and other interaction types.

Also don't forget to commit after running any of the commands so it submits the data to the LMS.

### What the modes mean

A `cmi.mode` of 'normal' means the LMS will accept changes to the student attempt. 'review' means you are taking a look at a prior attempt, but will be unable to make further changes.  Of course the LMS may ignore the specification on this.  The LMS was not specifically called out to record or display prior attempts so this feature is typically left to the LMS to manage.
Lastly 'browse' will similarly give you the ability to look at the content you are not assigned.  This does not typically persist any of the data you enter.
Hopefully that helps explaining why the modes are important.  Please note, not all content does a great job of conveying to the student that "I am not recording you" which leads to angry students when they lose their data.  As a content designer/developer its important to take these steps since people associate SCORM with being the problem vs. the actual implementation of the presentation.

To recap -

- `cmi.mode` lets you know if you can persist your data (commonly)
- `cmi.entry` lets you know if its the beginning or a resume
- `cmi.suspend_data` lets you know if you have data from a prior session to populate (I find it more reliable than cmi.entry in the wild)
- `cmi.location` lets you bookmark a page the student was on
- `cmi.exit` will specify if the student is ending or suspending the attempt.

Comment: Do you mean it is impossible to change already stored results for current attempt (score, success status, completion status).

Comment: It totally depends on whether your quiz has the ability to load data back into itself - if it has then simply resuming the quiz lets you change literally anything in it - why it can be important to check the `cmi.entry` loading state to know what you're meant to do. Exiting with anything other than `suspend` (or possibly `logout`) is generally the only way to actually finish a quiz as far as the platform is concerned.

Comment: A `cmi.exit` type of 'normal', 'logout', 'timeout' or '' signifies the end of the student attempt.  The LMS may allow the teacher to make further alterations, but typically the SCO would launch in a `cmi.mode` of 'review' there-after.  If however, the `cmi.exit` type is 'suspend', the student can resume the same attempt.  Further adjusting answers, other values as well as the status you mention.  Again like mentioned above this greatly depends if the content supports these features i.e. bookmarking, re-rendering Questions and Answers etc ...

Answer (score 0):

Generally you need to set `cmi.exit` to `"suspend"` in order to come back in and change things later, however I don't know WebTutor and whether that would work...

Comment: I think it wouldn't help. I'm not talking about situations, where I already sent 'cmi.completion_status' and 'cmi.success_status', not just left course in the middle of things.

Comment: You can change those values as much as you'd like until the SCO is marked as finished, even when you're resuming to allow someone to change their answers later...